# Embed in R markdown a googleVis chart generated using a function

Tags: r, plot, markdown, googlevis

I have a function that creates the same type of `googleVis` plot for different data frames. These plots are to be embedded in a Markdown file. Embedding a single plot with the `result='asis'` option fails to achieve my objective when the chart object is created by my function. Following is a dummy code for the same:

````
Embedded googleVis plots
=====================

Some text here

```{r}
library(googleVis)
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag="chart")
```

And now the plot

```{r result='asis', tidy=TRUE}
mark_func <- function(data) {
    data$Mean=mean(data$Popularity)
    CC <- gvisComboChart(data, xvar='City',
          yvar=c('Mean', 'Popularity'),
          options=list(seriesType='bars',
                       width=450, height=300,
                       title='City Popularity',
                       series='{0: {type:"line"}}'))
    return(CC)
}
```

```{r result='asis', tidy=TRUE}
plt <- mark_func(CityPopularity)
plot(plt)`
```
````

I am converting this Markdown file to a HTML using `knit2html` from the `knitr` package and viewing this HTML in Firefox. Instead of seeing a plot, I see a long HTML code.

What is it that I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Comment: why are you using result = 'asis'

Comment: Based on the suggestion here (might be outdated): http://www.r-bloggers.com/googlevis-0-3-2-is-released-better-integration-with-knitr/.

Removing it doesn't resolve the issue either.

Comment: does your code say result or results

Comment: I had written `result` instead of `results`. Ugggghhhh! Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

It is just typos. You are forgetting to escape your quotemarks at the end and the code chunk option should be **results**, not *result*.

Working code:

````
%\VignetteEngine{knitr::knitr}

```{r}
library(googleVis)
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag="chart")
```

```{r results='asis', tidy=TRUE}
mark_func <- function(d) {
    d$Mean=mean(d$Popularity)
    CC <- gvisComboChart(d, xvar='City',
          yvar=c('Mean', 'Popularity'),
          options=list(seriesType='bars',
                       width=450, height=300,
                       title='City Popularity',
                       series='{0: {type:\"line\"}}'))
    return(CC)
}
```

```{r results='asis', tidy=TRUE}
plt <- mark_func(CityPopularity)
plot(plt)
```
````